# Eclipse on the moon

Tags: the-moon, solar-eclipse, lunar-eclipse

What kinds of eclipse is seen by the person on the moon, when there is:

1. Solar eclipse on the earth, and
2. Lunar eclipse on the earth?

Comment: Have you seen the map of the moon's shadow track across the Earth when there is a solar eclipse? http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEmono/TSE2017/TSE2017fig/TSE2017-usa.jpg

Comment: So, the moon comes in between the sun and the earth in a straight line during solar eclipse

Comment: How else would the moon block the sun?

Comment: It completely covers the sun

Comment: The sun is large, and yet a small moon (relatively speaking) covers it entirely. Now the shadow casts by the moon lands on the Earth (which is larger than the moon). It makes sense to me that the shadow is smaller than the Earth, even though the moon hides the sun. It all depends on where you are. 500 miles south from the location of a total eclipse, may not have the moon hiding even touching the sun.

Comment: You might take a look at stellarium if you want a visual answer.

Answer (score 2):

This kinda depends on where you are on the moon.  If you're on the far side during a solar eclipse, you won't see a darn thing but the sun.  If you're on the near side, you will see the moon's shadow pass across the earth.  If you're on the far side during a lunar eclipse, you won't see anything but the stars. If you're on the near side, you will see the earth completely blot out the sun.  You should also see all the Earth's sunrises and sunsets at the same time (kinda cool!).